# magento installation - cannot login to backend

Tags: magento-1.9, database, install

This is my first Magento Installation -- and after dragging all my files from my Magento CMS install-download zip file > uncompressing > and then uploading via FTP to my server, I was sure it completed successfully as the Magento install instructions resolved in my browser. After completing instructions, I thought I was complete as I was able to login and view the 'front-end' of the eCommerce Magento Installation, but when trying to log into the back-end, I was not able to do it.

```
www.sample.com/index.php/admin/index/login/
```

I saw the 'login page' via above URL and but nothing would let me 'login' - nor would any credential reset. I tried going to the mySQL DB 'phpmyadmin' and locating the table.. except the 'table' did not exist. Why would the table not be generated with my Magento Installation?

Magento Version 1.9.2

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a clean install and did you go through the install progress in the browser (setting the language, currency, database information, etc.)? If you did, is there a file on your server in the app/etc folder named local.xml? And do other tables exist? Or is your database completely empty?

You might want to delete the file and go through the installation again. It looks to me that the there's no required information in the database yet.